# Which maven artifact should I depend on for replacing jackson-jaxrs-json-provider?

Tags: jersey, jackson, jax-rs, moxy, jersey-2.0

I'm planning to replace `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` with MOXy thing. I tried to comment on [MOXy is the New Default JSON-Binding Provider in GlassFish 4](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html) and had no luck.

My stack is as follows.

```
Jersey
Spring
MyBatis
```

I'm using `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` and providing a custom `ContextResolver`.

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
//@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver
    implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        super();
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(MapperFeature.USE_WRAPPER_NAME_AS_PROPERTY_NAME, true);
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> type) {
        return objectMapper;
    }

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
}
```

My questions are

1. which maven artifact should I depend on for replacing `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`? Is it `com.eclipsesource.jaxrs:provider-moxy`?
2. Is it the right way to work as described in above link? Note that my module is not for full featured AS, but for Tomcat.

Comment: Just curious -- is there specific reason for trying out MOXy for JSON? While it works well with XML, its JSON support is not really competitive, feature-, performance- or usability-wise. Jackson provider is the default by most JAX-RS implementations; and in particular DropWizard uses it and has simplified configuration.

Comment: @staxman No. I'm just experimenting those two implementations. And I got the same result since I depend on JAXB. Thanks for advice. I love Jackson.

Comment: ok just wanted to check if MOXy had some features you were missing or such. Nothing wrong in checking out alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Which maven artifact should I depend on for replacing `jackson-jaxrs-json-provide`? Is it `com.eclipsesource.jaxrs:provider-moxy`?

You should be using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

> 2. Is it the right way to work as described in above link? Note that my module is not for full featured AS, but for Tomcat.

Not really sure what you're asking here, but the `jersey-media-moxy` artifact doesn't use/depend on Jackson. So your use of `ObjectMapper` would not work. `ContextResolvers` with MOXy (JSON), would consist of using [`MoxyJsonConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/moxy/json/MoxyJsonConfig.html).

For other configurations of this artifact, the link you provided is a good place, and also [The Jersey User Guide for working with MOXy](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy)